# java.util.Formatter: UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'F'

Tags: java, date-formatting, iso8601

What's wrong with

```
public String toString() {
    return super.toString()
            + String.format(" %1$F-%2$F", startDate, endDate);
}
```

I get

> Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'F'
>     at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2606)
>     at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.(Formatter.java:2634)
>     at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2480)
>     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2414)
>     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2367)
>     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2769)

I wanted to print the ISO 8601 date defined in [`java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: How about using `T` for date/time. I don't know what `F` does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the date formatting patterns require a prefix:

```
't', 'T'    date/time   Prefix for date and time conversion characters. See Date/Time Conversions.
```

The example for the `F` modifier also shows this syntax:

```
'F'     ISO 8601 complete date formatted as "%tY-%tm-%td".
```

So the following pattern should work:

```
String.format(" %1$tF-%2$tF", startDate, endDate);
```